# Search for the root words using root words with prefixes or suffixes

Tags: select, sqlite, like

Is it possible to search the word "FILL" saved in the SQLite database using the words "REFILL" or "FILLED"? Not just these words specifically but you get the idea of searching the root word using the same word but with prefixes or suffixes.

I might get misunderstood as wanting to use the LIKE operator/command. But what I need is somehow reverse of that. The case is that the root words (FILL) are the ones in my database and the words that I am going to use in the query are those with prefixes or suffixes (e.g REFILL, FILLED)

I cannot use those word-trimming API because it's not going to be done in English. A code for android/Sqlite would be great but the query command is already a great help. Thaanks.

Comment: What's wrong with the % wildcard (unless I've misunderstood)? LIKE '%FILL%'? Or [regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071601/how-do-i-use-regex-in-a-sqlite-query)

Comment: So, what you need is something like full-text indexing for SQLite?

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about is "stemming" where a word -- refill -- is related to its "root" or "stem" word -- fill. This is usually implemented through Full Text Search, which I believe SQLite [supports](https://sqlite.org/fts5.html), though I've never used it.

To implement this yourself in your own tables and code will be a complex task requiring a thorough understanding of the target language(s), how word-forms are constructed and how the grammar is defined, both theoretically and in practice.